# intersection observer is not working in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I am creating an application which in the scroll I have use intersection observer so in that program one error is comming can not property of null reading foreach and do some scroll in that application and observer the viewport ,so how to make it correct in that program ,code is given below

```
export default function App() {
  const card = document.querySelector(".card");
  const ob = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        entry.target.classList.toggle("show", entry.isIntersecting);
        if (entry.isIntersecting) ob.unobserve(entry.target);
      });
    },
    {
      threshold: 1
    }
  );
  card.forEach((card) => {
    ob.observe(card);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="card-container">
        <div className="card show">This is a First card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a Last card</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `querySelector` in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the `intersectionObserver` initialization inside `useEffect`.

For Example -

```
export default function App() {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const card = document.querySelector(".card");
    const ob = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          entry.target.classList.toggle("show", entry.isIntersecting);
          if (entry.isIntersecting) ob.unobserve(entry.target);
        });
      },
      { 
        threshold: 1
      }
    );
    card.forEach((card) => {
      ob.observe(card);
    });
   }, []);
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="card-container">
        <div className="card show">This is a First card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a card</div>
        <div className="card">This is a Last card</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: if i wrap the initialization code inside useEffect then its throw error "card.forEach is not a function"

Comment: @SougataMukherjee replace `querySelector` by `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `document` outside of an effect in React, and in this particular case you are getting `null` on `document.querySelector` because those elements haven't been mounted yet when you call it.

You can easily solve your issue by moving everything into a `useEffect` hook, but it's still weird to use `document.querySelector` in React since you are essentially bypassing it.

Although in this case it's debatable. Depending on the context, those cards might come from an API call (since they look like an array), or your could manually a constant array with the data they need outside of your component.
The idea is to be able to use `.map` to iterate through them.

The point is this isn't always possible. Those cards might be separate static sections of a landing page with completely different shapes and components, and in that case you have two approaches:

- One is two add a `ref` on the container, and iterate through its child nodes in the effect (instead of using `document.querySelector` you would use `ref.current.children`).
- The other is to do like you are doing, using some sort of query selector.

Comment: if i wrap the initialization code inside useEffect then its throw error "card.forEach is not a function"